# Ruby Sinatra table from MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby, database, sinatra

I am currently working on a project where I have to pull data from a MySQL database and display the data in a table using Ruby Sinatra.

I was able to connect to the database and pull the data and put it inside an array.

Example of table in database

`City        Country
 Dallas      USA 
 Tokyo       Japan`

Example of what array looks like

["Dallas, USA", "Tokyo, Japan"]

Now, how would I display the array to look exactly like the table from the database. Or, is there a way where I can completely copy the table from the database onto the webpage?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your_app/routes.rb:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'slim'

get '/' do

  raw_data = [
    "Dallas, USA", 
    "Tokyo,Japan", 
    "Munich,    Germany",
  ]

  @results = {}

  raw_data.each do |item|
    city, country = item.split(/, \s* /x)
    @results[city] = country
  end

  p results # {"Dallas"=>"USA", "Tokyo"=>"Japan", "Munich"=>"Germany"}

  slim :index 

end
```

your_app/views/layout.slim:

```
doctype html 
html
  head 
    meta charset="utf-8"
    title Test
    css:
      th {text-align:left}
      table {width: 15em}
  body 
    h1 This is the Layout.  Find me in your_app/views/layout.slim
    == yield
```

Note the css, which left aligns the column headers--otherwise the column headers will be centered.

your_app/views/index.slim:

```
table 
  thead
    tr
      th City
      th Country

  tbody
  - @results.each do |city, country|
    tr
      td = city
      td = country
```

Result:

[image]

**Edit:**

To use the jquery program tablesorter, download [tablesorter](https://github.com/christianbach/tablesorter), then unzip/untar it, then move the newly created directory, `tablesorter-master`, into the directory `your_app/public/`.

You can use these files:

your_app/views/layout.slim:

```
doctype html 
html
  head 
    meta charset="utf-8"
    title Test
    link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="tablesorter-master/themes/green/style.css"
  body 
    h1 This is the Layout.  Find me in your_app/views/layout.slim
    == yield 

    script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" !<= the link
    script src="tablesorter-master/jquery.tablesorter.js"
    script src="hookup_tablesorter.js"
```

your_app/public/hookup_tablesorter.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
  { 
    $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
  } 
);
```

your_app/views/index.slim:

```
table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"
  thead
    tr
      th City
      th Country

  - @results.each do |city, country|
    tr
      td = city
      td = country
```

Note the changes above. Slim adds a tbody tag automatically, therefore explicitly adding a tbody tag in the Slim template creates two tbody tags which screws up tablesorter.

Then you will see this:

[image]

And clicking on the column headers will sort the rows.  You need an internet connection to link to the jquery file.  As an alternative, you can download jquery, and put it in the directory `your_app/public/`, then link to it:

```
doctype html 
html
  head 
    meta charset="utf-8"
    title Test
    link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="tablesorter-master/themes/green/style.css"
  body 
    h1 This is the Layout.  Find me in your_app/views/layout.slim
    == yield 

    script src="jquery.min.js"
    script src="tablesorter-master/jquery.tablesorter.js"
    script src="js_ready.js"
```

If you don't like that table style, tablesorter also has a blue theme:

[image]

And people have created other [styles](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/4mVfu/1/).

Comment: Thanks for the help! Just wondering, is there a way where I can literally transfer the table from the database onto the webpage so it would be easier to have functionality such as sorting the columns based on names?

Comment: @Tom, You are using a web browser to show the user some data, but a web browser does not understand database commands.  Rather, a web browser understands html and javascript.  You can construct an html table and use javascript/jquery to respond to clicks on a column header, and then sort the rows based on the values in that column.

Comment: @Tom, Is it your desire to show the user a text field where they enter database commands to sort the table?

Comment: @7stdu, not quite. I was thinking of just having a ascending and descending arrows or something.

Comment: @Tom, Okay, you can do that with javascript/jquery.

Comment: @Tom, Here is a pre-built jquery table that has sortable columns: http://tablesorter.com/docs/  Because google hosts jquery, you don't even need to download jquery, you can get the jquery library by putting the following in your html page: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @Tom, I added a tablesorter example.